# My below java code says runtime error in the input section

Tags: java, runtime

Here is my following java code.But I can't understand what is happening as when I run it through JCPP editor my local machine it doesn't shows any error but in case of online compiler it shows runtime error.
Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class string1
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String arr[]=new String[a];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=br.readLine();
        }
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            int b=arr[i].indexOf("not");
            if(b==-1)
            {

                System.out.println("regularly fancy");
            }
            else
            {
                if(arr[i].charAt(b+3)==' ')
                System.out.println("Real Fancy");
                else
                    System.out.println("regularly fancy");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The error is showing here is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Codechef.main(Main.java:14)
```

Please help me out with this as I have tried a lot to find out the solution but I can't.

Comment: A runtime error is at runtime. Nothing to do with compilation. How does your online runtime function?

Comment: in main function it takes integer value that is no of test cases after that strings

Comment: You didn't understand me. **What** is your "online runtime"? **How** are you running this?

Comment: Runtime is 0.11 sec

Comment: I am running this using codechef compiler

Comment: Clearly you're trying to read more lines than are in the input. And you never have to import anything in `java.lang`.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using "Codechef". Click the box that says "Custom Input", then add your input for the runtime like

[image: Codechef with Custom Input]

Or, with your [provided input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058691/my-below-java-code-says-runtime-error-in-the-input-section#comment94951501_54058777) from the comments

[image: Second screenshot with provided input]

Comment: @AlokSarkar What Input did you provide? I literally ran your code. See screenshot.

Comment: @AlokSarkar See screenshot.